# String stream by columns in R

Tags: r, stringstream

I have a logfile with a lot of information. Example:

```
event_type| video                    |id
------------------------------------------------ 
load      | Video -math              | 21
load      | Video -math              | 21
load      | Video - Math and Speed   | 22
play      | Video -math              | 21
seek      | Video -math              | 21
pause     | Video -math              | 21
seek      | Video -math              | 21
play      | Video -math              | 21
pause     | Video -math              | 21
play      | Video - Math and Speed   | 22
pause     | Video - Math and Speed   | 22
stop      | Video - Math and Speed   | 22
stop      | Video - Math and Speed   | 21
seek      | Video -math              | 22
```

I want to make a string stream by id and video.

```
  id    Video -math                             Video - Math and Speed              
 21  |   load-load-play-seek-pause-play-pause  | stop
 22  |   seek                                  | load-play-pause-stop
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please `dput()` part of your file?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a very common pattern: group by variables, and then summarize. Here's a straightforward way to accomplish that using the `dplyr` package which lets us easily and coherently manipulate dataframes:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id, video) %>% 
  summarize(events = paste(event_type ,collapse = "-"))
```

However, this gives us the following output:

```r
 # A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   id [?]
     id video                  events              
  <int> <fct>                  <chr>               
1  21   Video -math            load-load-play-seek…
2  21   Video - Math and Speed stop                
3  22   Video -math            seek                
4  22   Video - Math and Speed load-play-pause-stop
```

This data is in a ["tidy"](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) format - a row for each observation. But your final output shows that you want the data in a non-tidy format. To change the shape of the data, another package, `tidyr`, comes in handy.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id, video) %>% 
  summarize(events = paste(event_type ,collapse = "-")) %>%
  spread(key = video, value = events)
```

spreading the `video` column, and using the `events` column for the variables, will give you your desired result.

Comment: Honest question, instead of loading every package, why not to load `tidyverse`?

Comment: I believe it's important to understand the different parts of the tidyverse packages. dplyr and its data manipulation functions, tidyr and its data reshaping functions, etc. Using `library(tidyverse)` is a convenient shortcut once you're already fluent in the tidyverse.